# Using Mathematica for solving circuit problems

Tags: equation-solving, engineering

This is a broad question, I need general help regarding this. I have to solve some electric circuits using Mathematica, software I've never used before. So, my question is, where to start? I believe there won't be any issues once I know what I'm actually supposed to do but I have no clue on how to write anything.
I was thinking about getting [this book](https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=6010), however it's 700 pages long and I'm not sure whether that will help at all, given the purpose I need Mathematica for.

Any helpful resources I can use or maybe some example circuits solved?

Comment: See [`The Wolfram Language: FAST INTRODUCTION FOR PROGRAMMERS`](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/)

Comment: There are also several [demonstrations](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Circuit+Design) that might be helpful.

Comment: It is very VERY old and thus you would have to be cautious about compatibility with a far newer version of Mathematica, but there was at least one book published trying to introduce engineers to analyzing electronic circuits using Mathematica. "Applied Electronic Engineering With Mathematica" available used for $1.95+shipping. You might see if it provides an introduction to Mathematica within the area that you want to tackle. There might have been another similar book, but I can't remember the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Some examples in Docs:

- [Docs on NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html): Examples >> Applications >> Electrical Systems
- [Docs on StateSpaceModel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html): Examples >> Applications >> Electrical Systems
- [Docs on WhenEvent](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html): Examples >> Applications >> Power Electronics / Digital Control

### Some other examples:

- [Analyze an Electric Circuit](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-graphs-and-networks/analyze-an-electric-circuit.html)
- [Transistor Amplifier Circuit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/TransistorAmplifierCircuit.html)
- [RLC Circuit Driven by Periodic Signal and White Noise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/RLCCircuitDrivenByPeriodicSignalAndWhiteNoise.html)
- [Control an RLC Circuit Modeled as a Descriptor System](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ControlAnRLCCircuitModeledAsADescriptorSystem.html)
- [DC-DC Buck Converter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/DCDCBuckConverter.html)

### Demonstrations:

- [CIRCUIT DESIGN](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Circuit%20Design)
- [ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Electrical%20Engineering)
- [ELECTRONICS](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Electronics)

### An overview:

- [The Wolfram Solution for Electrical Engineering](https://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/electrical-engineering/)

### Other Wolfram Systems:

- [System Modeler: Examples](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/examples/electrical-engineering/)
- [System Modeler: Component-Based—Simple Circuit](https://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/GettingStarted/ComponentBasedSimpleCircuit.html)
- [Wolfram|Alpha Examples](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/science-and-technology/engineering/electrical-engineering/electric-circuits/)